# Print Grid of Strings and LateX prettyprint?

Tags: latex, printing

I want to include a table (or really a Grid) object in my notebook that explains what mathematical expressions some variables in my code correspond to. For example, if I have the variable `GammaAbc` I want my Grid to have a row

| “GammaAbc" | $\Gamma^{a}_{\,b\,c}$ |
| --- | --- |

I can’t seem to get the pretty-printing right by the `CTR + 4` inline latex input.  Any alternatives?

Comment: I should mention that I’m fine with writing the Grid by hand, I don’t need a systematic way to convert the variables into LaTeX.

Comment: You can try to add a subscript using any of the ways described [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/EnterSubscriptsAndSuperscripts.html). Does one of them fit your needs?

Comment: That unfortunately fails for more complicated expressions, like $ ^{(n-1)} \widehat{\gamma}_{a,\, b}$ for instance. I’m looking to enter the expression through LaTeX only.